Различаются значения при выполнении функции поиска элемента selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time

arts = [
    '840055507'
]
cards = []
def saveCardInfo(art):

    cst = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[data-widget^='webPrice']")
    print(cst.text.split('\n'))
    print(cst.text)

def initDriver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    stealth(driver,
    platform="Win32")
    return driver

driver = initDriver()
driver.get('https://www.ozon.ru/')

for art in arts:
    time.sleep(1)
    srch_inp = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'input')
    srch_inp.send_keys(f"{art}\n")
    saveCardInfo(art)

driver.quit()

Код выше парсит определенные товары на озоне. Есть проблемы с получением цены товара:
При выполнении кода выводит следующее:
['1\u2009151\u2009₽', 'c Ozon Картой', '1\u2009187\u2009₽', '4\u2009290\u2009₽', 'без Ozon Карты']
1 151 ₽
c Ozon Картой
1 187 ₽
4 290 ₽
без Ozon Карты
Проблема заключается в том, одни и те же значения различаются, а именно сам ценник товара. К примеру, если просто принтить то выведет - "1 151 ₽",а если это заносить в список или переменную будет выглядеть как '1\u2009151\u2009₽'.Пробовал еще BeatifulSoup, результат тот же
С чем это может быть связано и что с этим можно сделать?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
